# Viscous forces acting on a thin square plate moving along the top surface of a water tank

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics

> Consider a thin square plate floating on a viscous liquid in a large tank. The height ݄ of the
> liquid in the tank is much less than the width of the tank. The floating plate is pulled
> horizontally with a constant velocity $u_o$.଴Which of the following statements is (are) true?
>
> (A) The resistive force of liquid on the plate is inversely proportional to ݄$h$
>
> (B) The resistive force of liquid on the plate is independent of the area of the plate
>
> (C) The tangential (shear) stress on the floor of the tank increases with $u_o$
>
> (D) The tangential (shear) stress on the plate varies linearly with the viscosity $\eta$ of the liquid
>
> JEE advanced 2018

The logic to solve was to consider the high school equation of viscosity:

$$ F= \eta A \frac{ \partial v}{\partial h}$$

And from the above equation A,B,D is inferred. However, I can only see why it should be so for $\eta$.

Firstly, we don't know what type of function the velocity of the plate will be with height. So, we can't really say it would be increasing with C, and I am not sure how we can conclude A with knowing the explicit functional form. Are there some assumptions we could use to still conclude the options with the given information?

Second point is I can't find why it is important that height is much more larger than width, could someone explain significance of that point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concerning the first part of your question: Of course the dynamics can become arbitrarily complicated if we try to push for it. For example, many of the statements might become wrong if you move the plate too fast, because at some point turbulences and non trivial behavior, that is not captured by the formula that you quoted to solve the problem, becomes relevant. All in all the solution you suggested seems to be completely fine though and I am not sure what else exactly you are asking for.

Concerning the second point: If the width of the tank was too small you would encounter additional complications due to the interaction of the fluid with the walls of the tank. The assumption about the width is basically a nice way of saying "Assume the tank is infinitly large so that you don't have to worry about complicated stuff that happens at the walls of a real tank".

Comment: Hmm couldn't the same interaction be present if length was les